# About the MacMahon functions on dimensions bigger than Three

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

As is well known, the generating functions of partitions counting in dimension 2 and 3 admit closed formulas. These functions show up in Euler characterisitics of Hilbert scheme of points in surfaces and threefolds respectively. But in dimension bigger than three, we do not have a closed formula. My question is whether there is any plausible reason for that.